# Estimate the value of a nonnegative harmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Suppose $u:B(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a nonnegative harmonic function such that $u(0,0)=1$. What is the best estimation I can get for $u(\frac{1}{2},0)$?

Since
\begin{align}
u(0)&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{B(0,1)}u(x,y)dxdy \\
    &\geq\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{B(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})}u(x,y)dxdy \\
    &=\frac{1}{4}u(\frac{1}{2}),
\end{align}
I can get an estimation that $0\leq u(\frac{1}{2})\leq 4$. But it seems far from the best. To get the equality from above, we need that $u(x,y)=0$ for $(x,y)\in B(0,1)\setminus B(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, which seems impossible to be true.

Any advice will be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u$ is harmonic and non-negative in the unit disk then [Harnack's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harnack%27s_inequality) gives
$$
\frac{1-r}{1+r} u(0) \le u(z) \le \frac{1+r}{1-r} u(0)
$$
for $|z|  = r$. If $u(0) = 1$ then
$$\frac 13 \le u\left(\frac 12\right) \le 3 \, .$$

These bounds are sharp, as the functions
$$
 u_1(z) = \operatorname{Re} \left( \frac{1- z}{1+ z}\right) \, ,  \,
 u_2(z) = \operatorname{Re} \left( \frac{1+ z}{1- z}\right)
$$
show.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience!